# shortest record type in Modula-2

Tags: syntax, ebnf, modula-2

Homework assignment
1.  Give an example of the shortest **record type** in Modula-2. (“Shortest” means fewest number of lexemes.)

EBNF definition of **RECORD**

```
RecordType = RECORD FieldListSequence END.

FieldListSequence = FieldList {“;” FieldList}.

FieldList = [IdentList ";" Type | CASE [Ident] ";" 
Qualident OF Variant  {"|" Variant} ELSE FieldListSequence]END].
```

WHat i came up with  is  ...am i close

```
RecordType = RECORD, FieldList, END.
```

Answer (score 3):

That is not legal M2 syntax for any M2 dialect.

The shortest field list is a single field declaration:

```
field : SomeType
```

Thus, the shortest record type definition is:

```
TYPE Foo = RECORD
  bar : Baz
END;
```

This is valid for all dialects.

UPDATE:

As mentioned in my comment to learn EBNF, I recommend to study railroad diagrams and compare them to the EBNF. Here is a link to the syntax diagrams of Modula-2 specifically for the 4th edition of Wirth's book "Programming in Modula-2", aka PIM4.

http://modula-2.info/m2pim/pmwiki.php/SyntaxDiagrams/PIM4NonTerminals

The diagram for record types is at:

http://modula-2.info/m2pim/pmwiki.php/SyntaxDiagrams/PIM4NonTerminals#recordType

Comment: However, you should really do your homework on your own ;-)

A hint perhaps, if you have difficulties with the EBNF, draw some railroad diagrams to visualise the syntax. You can find a script for drawing M2 syntax diagrams on my bitbucket repo (search on nickname).